# Dojo dijit.Editor tabbing

Tags: dojo, editor, tabs

I want to provide javascript editing with highlighting in my web page. I am looking around for a good text area and I found dijit.Editor, however, I also need to have tabbed browsing for different files (a.js , b.js , c.js , ... , z.js). dijit.Editor seems to have tabs along the top (see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Editor.html)) but I can't tell if those are built in, or if they can be assigned.

Can someone please either answer my question, or recommend a different editor to use.
Cheers

Comment: Which tabs do you mean? If you're referring to the "Demo, Copy&Paste, Javascript" tabs in the demo windows, those are not part of `dijit.Editor`.  They're merely part of the demonstration engine Dojo uses for its widgets.  The Editor widget is just the toolbar of buttons and textarea beneath it.

Comment: The tabs in those demos are most likely a `dijit.layout.TabContainer` tab widget.  If this is what you needed to know, I can copy the info down as an answer below.

Comment: Michael, thanx. That's exactly what I meant. I couldn't figure out how those worked. I didn't want to beat my head against the wall learning how the Editor worked if it only had "Demom Copy&Past, Javascript" as tabs.

Comment: Great.  I put this info down as an answer. Accept if you wish. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the "Demo, Copy&Paste, Javascript" tabs in the demo windows, those are not part of dijit.Editor. They're merely part of the demonstration engine Dojo uses for its widgets. The Editor widget is just the toolbar of buttons and textarea beneath it.

The tabs in those demos are most likely a `dijit.layout.TabContainer` tab widget.

I've used `dijit.Editor` in a few projects and find it to be extremely flexible.  The other major benefit is its close integration to the rest of the Dojo toolkit and Dijit widgets.  The API is very consistent and well-organized across the Dojo platform, and you won't  muchfind yourself searching for plugins of varying quality as with jQuery.

Comment: Michael, what I need is the javascript highlight capabilities (as in the 'javascript' tab) but in the text area. Is this possible?

Comment: @puk The syntax highlighting most likely done with `dojox.highlight` It's probably possible apply it inside of `dijit.Editor`, but I have no idea how. http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/highlight.

Answer (score 1):

see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654850/dojo-xml-editor-widget)

dijit.Editor is based on contentEditable and while that's great for rich text editing and short snippets of text, it is not the ideal text editor for code.  The underlying browser mechanism for contentEditable doesn't scale particularly well for long files, and there's unnecessary wiring for rich text, variable spacing and such.  I have seen a couple of people build an editor out of dijit.Editor and dojox.highlight and you may find that sufficient (sorry, I don't remember exactly where ATM)

Comment: The Orion editor looks the nicest but ultimitely I went with Ace as it caters the most to programmers. CODE POWER!

Comment: Peller, upon further inspection I thought I should let you, and anyone else reading this know that, although Ace is a very nice editor, the code is very poorly written. There are hardly any comments, there are numerous bad practices (like using `if` without curly brackets) and the code is spread across multiple scripts, but they still reference the same variables/functions.