# Dojo XML editor Widget

Tags: xml, editor, dojo

Do you know if there are any Dojo XML editor widgets? Looking for something that would provide basic XML editing, like this highlighting XML syntax... validation is not important, just syntax highlighting...

I know of dijit.Editor and dojox.highlight... but how do I combine these two to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dijit.Editor isn't ideal for source code editing.  It's a rich text editor good for relatively small snippets of text.

Try looking at [Eclipse Orion](http://www.eclipse.org/orion/)  You can apply dojox.highlight as a styler.  You should also look at [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and [Bespin/Skywriter/Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/)